# Replace value in colum

Tags: r, replace

I'm a beginner and I'm already stuck on something simple. I want to change the values ​​in the class column from `1`, `2`, `3` to `1st`, `2nd`, and `3rd`.

I tried several things like `replace(x, list, values)` but I think I'm overthinking too much (with the $ and the C, but I think it's more simple than that)

Only 1,2 and 3 occur in the class column

Or do I have to work with `TRUE`, `FALSE`?

Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can do this in many ways.
One way, in `base R`, is with a nested `ifelse` operation:

```
df$class <- ifelse(df$class==1, "1st", ifelse(df$class==2, "2nd", "3rd"))
df
  class
1   1st
2   2nd
3   3rd
4   1st
5   3rd
6   1st
7   2nd
8   3rd
```

Alternatively, using `stringr`, you can use `setNames` and `str_replace_all`:

```
replacements <- setNames(c("1st", "2nd", "3rd"),    # new forms
                        c(1,2,3))                   # old forms
library(stringr)
df$class <- str_replace_all(df$class, replacements)
```

Yet another option is `dplyr`s functions `mutate`and `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(class = case_when(class == 1 ~ "1st",
                           class == 2 ~ "2nd",
                           TRUE ~ "3rd"))
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  class = c(1,2,3,1,3,1,2,3)
)
```

Comment: Much helpfull! There are more ways to do this ;)

Comment: If my answer was of any help please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.